# Java - Hashing/Encryption Across Servers

Tags: java, cookies, encryption, hash, cryptography

I am looking for a method to securely hash data in a Cookie. I have a farm of servers and any of the servers could issue the Cookie and any of the servers needs to be able to validate the contents of the cookie.

I as thinking of doing soomething like:

Cookie Contents:

```
SHA(<secret-uuid><user-id><expiration-date>)|<user-id>|<expiration-date>
```

For example:

```
122233344444|bob|2012-01-01-12-01-03
```

When validating the cookie i can simply re-hash the "clear text data" to the hashed value:

```
SHA1(<secret-uuid>bob2012-01-01-12-01-03) == 122233344444
```

Currently I have to manually set a  in a configuration file and ensure theyre the same between every server in the farm.

Is there any "safe" way to programmatically generate a SECRET-UUID that will be the same across all machines? Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Comment: You could encrypt it using a key that all the servers in the farm can use to decrypt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is an [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hmac). You should use the HMAC algorithm rather than trying to invent your own - it's designed to negate several possible attacks against naive ways to construct a keyed hash.

The key (what you call the 'secret uuid') has to be distributed to all the machines, and there's no magical cryptographic way to avoid that. Presumably you have some way to deploy code and configuration; you should use that same method to distribute the key.

One alternative would be to have a 'cookie server' that creates and verifies cookies; individual machines can query it as needed.